# How To Run Java File in Rhel 5 Terminal?

Tags: java, linux, daemon

Hi I am new to linux and I'm trying to run java file. I am following this site:

http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/7.htm

in "installation instruction" when I reach to,

```
javac JavaDaemonTest.java
```

I found error command not found then I go to the place where I install jdk 1.6

usr/java/jdk1.6/bin here I found javac command and then I try to run

```
 javac JavaDaemonTest.java
```

still I am getting 'command not found error'

my environment variable in bash profile is set that is,

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_29/
export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-5.5.34-src/servletapi/jsr152/examples/WEB-INF/lib/jstl.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-5.5.34-src/servletapi/jsr152/examples/WEB-INF/lib/jstl.jar
export PATH
unset USERNAME
```

how to get out of it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

its nothing about Java here, its just your shell doesn't know where to search for javac
Add to the $PATH env. variable your $JAVA_HOME/bin and try again. It should work now

Comment: @ how to add it what would be my environment variable would look like after changing it just tell me here by using my environment variable which i mentioned above..

Comment: In ubuntu I've used something like this:   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_29 and then export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH then you should rerun your script and it should solve your issue

Comment: Have you run your bash_profile again? Something like ". ~/.bash_profile ?" After this command what is your path (please output here the results of the following command: echo $PATH

Comment: You should also ensure you've installed jdk with appropriate permissions, maybe you just can't access the javac because of lack of permissions?